# Any idea about N-topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

In *[Bitopological spaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-13.1.71)*, Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) **13** (1963) 71–89 [MR0143169](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=143169), J.C. Kelly introduced the idea of bitopological spaces. Is there any paper concerning the generalization of this concept, i.e. a space with any number of topologies?

Comment: FWIW: Among the $\sim\!50$ papers that cite this paper on MathSciNet, there seems to be none that mentions $n$-topological spaces.

Comment: This [paper](http://zabidin.blog.umt.edu.my/files/2009/08/Mapp-and-pair-conti-on-pair-Lindelof.pdf) talks about n-topological spaces a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

For $n=3$ Google turns up mention of AL-Fatlawee J.K. *On paracompactness in bitopological spaces and tritopological spaces*, MSc. Thesis, University of Babylon (2006). [Asmahan Flieh Hassan](http://edu.kufauniv.com/t/asmahan.f/researchs.html) at the University of Kufa, also in Iraq, also seems to be interested in tritopological spaces and has worked with a Luay Al-Sweedy at the Univ. of Babylon. [This paper](http://individual.utoronto.ca/philipkremer/onlinepapers/TopS4xS5.pdf) by Philip Kremer makes use of tritopological spaces in a study of bimodal logics, as does [this paper by J. van Benthem et al.](http://www.illc.uva.nl/Publications/ResearchReports/PP-2004-15.text.pdf), which Kremer cites. In my admittedly limited experience with the area these are very unusual, in that they make use of a tritopological structure to study something else; virtually every other paper that I’ve seen on bi- or tritopological spaces has studied them for their own sake, usually in an attempt to extend topological notions in some reasonably nice way.

I’ve seen nothing more general than this.

Comment: I admit that I never heard of bitopological spaces before, and I hope I don't offend anybody by asking bluntly: What would be the showcase application of these ideas?

Comment: I’d seen them before, but I’d never seen anything resembling an application until I ran into the logic papers that I mentioned. To be brutally honest, most of what I’d seen looked like make-work papers -- excuses to attend conferences, résumé padding, etc. -- though some was a bit more interesting, if a bit of a dead end. (Dead ends per se don’t bother me, by the way; I’m perfectly happy to investigate an idea for its own sake if it interests me.)

Comment: Thank you for confirming my impression. I have nothing against dead ends either, but I was a bit overwhelmed by the sheer number of papers on that topic, so I was hoping for at least some mildly interesting applications "outside the field".

Comment: @Theo: AFAIK one of the motivation to study bitopological spaces are *asymmetric metric spaces* or *quasi-metric spaces*, e.g. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371174 I think they were also defined in Kelly's paper. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/examples-of-non-symmetric-distances Quasi-metric generates two topologies on the given space in very natural way.

Comment: @Martin: Sure, thanks. I'm aware of this example. But Kelly's paper doesn't contain anything that I'd call an application (a reasonable definition of an application: a result that doesn't mention the objects of study in the statement but uses them in the proof).

Comment: @Theo: I am not sure, if there's anything interesting in there, but this book has a chapter named "Applications of Bitopologies." http://books.google.com/books?id=Drp6v_Un0sMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22bitopological+spaces%22+applications&hl=en&ei=_R0tTsKXMsSq-Ab3ttHsDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=applications&f=false

Comment: @Martin: Thanks again, I appreciate it. I'll have look if I stumble upon it next time I'm in the library. @Brian: sorry about all those pings.`

Comment: @Theo: No problem; I was interested to see that anything like the Dvalishvili book existed, though I doubt that I’ll try to track it down, even now that I’m retired.

Comment: @Brian: It seems that this discussion would better be continued here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53612/where-do-bitopological-spaces-naturally-occur-have-they-applications

Comment: @Theo Buehler, Martin, Brian: Thanks a lot for the information you have given.I was busy with the construction and now I am happy to tell you that I have finally developed some elementary theory of N-topological structures.I am little confused regarding the choice of the journal.Can you suggest me the journal appropriate for such work?

Comment: @Martin: Since you won't be pinged by Kamran's comment, here's a ping for you.

Comment: @Kamran: It is very difficult to suggest something without knowing a bit on the paper. The most obvious algorithm is to see whether one of the *recent* papers which you extend is in a journal that might accept your paper. No offense, but the short time (about a month) in which you developed this theory makes me wonder if it wouldn't be worthwhile to invest some more time and effort before trying to have it accepted.

Comment: @Buehler: I had some idea of this construction before I asked this question. I wanted to be sure that there were no papers introducing this idea. I followed the approach of Kelly and used the ideas of generalized metric introduced by Mustafa [Zead Mustafa and Brailey Sims, ”A New Approach to Generalized Metric Spaces”,
Journal of Nonlinear and Convex Analysis, 7 (2), (2006 ). 289–297.]

Answer (score 1):

I close the question with the following answer-

On the possibility of N-topological spaces, International Journal of Mathematical Archive-3(7), 2012, 2520-2523
(http://www.ijma.info/index.php/ijma/article/view/1442)