# Applications of Bitopological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do bitopological spaces naturally occur? Do they have applications?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53612/where-do-bitopological-spaces-naturally-occur-do-they-have-applications)

J.C.Kelly introduced the idea of bitopological space [Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 13 (1963) 71–89 MR0143169, J.C. Kelly]. can some one tell me about its application with in Mathematics(such as in algebraic topology and geometry) and computer science?

Comment: Please don't crosspost here and on [mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100102/bitopological-spaces-and-algebraic-topology).