# A basic question on symmetry of metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In the metric space definiton, the second condition for a metric i.e. symmetry (d(p,q)=d(q,p)) is present. But, I have not seen any example where this condition has been used. Can anyone give any such example

Actually, in the analysis book of Rudin, all the theorems can be proved without using this property. I have not found any case where this property has been used. If anyone has any knowledge please share. What kind of results can't be proved using this property.

Comment: This page may be of interest to you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/examples-of-non-symmetric-distances

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis: Thanks. But, I want to see some theorems where this property has been used to prove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Examples of non symmetric distances](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/examples-of-non-symmetric-distances)