# Symmetry of metric spaces.

Tags: metric-spaces

Does that just say that the distance from $a$ to $b$ equals the distance from $b$ to $a$? Is that the definition of symmetry in the metric spaces?

Comment: In case it is interesting for you, here is a discussion of spaces where the symmetry condition is omitted, only the remaining conditions from the definition of metric spaces are required: [Examples of non symmetric distances](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/examples-of-non-symmetric-distances).

Answer (score 1):

That may depend on where you got the term "symmetry of metric space" from. What you're describing is the symmetry axiom of metric spaces. The axioms for metric spaces are

1. $d(x,y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$ (coincidence axiom)
2. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ (axiom of symmetry)
3. $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,x)$ (triangle axiom)

I've seen a reference that calls a space for "symmetric space" where only the two first axioms are required, but this seem to be non-standard. In that case every metric space will also be a so called "symmetric space".