# Metric that satisfies every property but symmetry

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose that we have a function $d:M\times M\to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies every property of a metric except we have that $d(x,y)\neq d(y,x)$.

Is there any interesting theories that arise from this assumption?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/examples-of-non-symmetric-distances

Comment: That post is merely asking for a metric that doesn't satisfy symmetries, I'm asking for theories that stem from the assumption.

Comment: They are called quasi-metric spaces. [See this](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiSnv367e7JAhVHJI4KHZYqC1QQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dcs.warwick.ac.uk%2Fpmetric%2Fmonthly708-718.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEQKNx55MosRBJER6LF_CT_zH3QOg)

Comment: Related: [Are there any “spaces” that violate symmetry of metric spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1685293)