# Proving that if a function is a metric then it is symmetric and non negative

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that given a metric d using only the properties that it $d(a,b)=0 iff a=b$ and $d(a,c)\le d(a,b)+d(b,c)$ that  $d(a,b)=d(b,a)$ and $d(a,b) \gt 0$ I understand that it is part of the definition in most texts but it is left as an exercise in mine and I can not figure it out.

I edited my original question. I stated wrong we do not have that $d(a,a)=0$ I have that $d(a,b)=0 iff a=b$

Comment: If you have symmetry, nonnegativity follows from $0=d(x,x) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,x) = 2 d(x,y)$. I don't think that symmetry follows automatically from the remaining axioms. But I don't have a counterexample right now.

Comment: @PhoemueX That doesn't prove that $d(x,y)\neq 0$?

Comment: @user160738: That surely does not follow from the stated axioms. Consider $d \equiv 0$ as an example. So I assumed (without mentioning it) that the OP just meant $d(a,b) \geq 0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, that's true. This is a bit weird because had it been the case other axioms followed from the two stated then we would not require them as axioms. I'm not sure what OP actually wants...

Comment: I edited the original question I misstated one of the axioms and @phoemuex I have the nonnegativity part if I can prove the symmetry part but I have had absolutely no luck with that

Comment: This could be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/examples-of-non-symmetric-distances

Comment: Maybe the OP wants to state the triangle inequality like $d(a,c) \leq d(b,a) + d(b,c)$ or something like this? Then (taking $b=c$) we get $d(a,c) \leq d(c,a)+d(c,c) = d(c,a)$, which easily yields symmetry.

Comment: @PhoemueX : this definition would lead to the solution, but I feel as if it forgot the intuitive part of the inequality : the shortest path is straight ahead ! ^^

Comment: @phoemuex yes you are correct I apparently can not read. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $d:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $d(a,b)=0$ is such that :

- $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}, d(a,a)=0,$
- $\forall a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},d(a,c)=0\leq d(a,b)+d(a,c)=0$

but you have not that $a\neq b\implies d(a,b)>0,$ so this point should be an axiom.

For the symmetry part, consider $d':\{0,1\}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as :
$$d'(0,0)=0,d'(1,1)=0,d'(1,0)=1 \text{ and } d'(0,1)=2.$$
Now note that :

- $\forall a\in\{0,1\},d'(a,a)=0,$
- $\forall a,b,c\in\{0,1\},d'(a,c)\leq d'(a,b)+d'(b,c)$

but $d'(0,1)=2\neq 1=d'(1,0),$ so that point should be an axiom too.