# Show that d is a metric if it fulfills triangle inequality and $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have the following exercise:

> $M$ is a non empty set and $d: M\times M \to \mathbb R$ and
>   application such that:
>
> a) $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$
>
> b) $d(x,z) \le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$
>
> show that $d$ is a metric

Aren't those 2 of the properties for a metric space? Also, wouldn't $b)$ imply that:

$$d(x,x)\le d(x,y)+d(y,x) \implies 0 \le d(x,y)+d(y,x)$$

which if we accept that $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$:

$$0 \le 2d(x,y) \implies d(x,y) \ge 0$$
?

So, wouldn't it be necessary for a metric space to have only:

$$d(x,y)\ge 0$$
$$d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$$
$$d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$$
?

What am I not getting here?

UPDATE: the right question is:

> $M$ is a non empty set and $d: M\times M \to \mathbb R$ and
>   application such that:
>
> a) $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$
>
> b) $d(x,z) \le d(x,y)+d(z,y)$
>
> show that $d$ is a metric

Comment: I don't see the exercise... What is the claim? The problem in what you are doing above is "if we accept that".

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp sorry, edited

Comment: Ok.Obviously, you have to show that $d(x,y)\ge 0$ and $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ holds for all $x,y$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp but $d(x,y)\ge 0$ can be shown if we accept $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$, so why do we need this assumption for metric spaces?

Comment: I don't understand this question. The task here is to show that you don't need any of these two assumptions.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp why we need to assume that $d(x,y)\ge 0$, in a metric space, if the triangular inequality + the assumption that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ implies that $d(x,y)\ge 0$, as I did in my question?

Comment: These two properties arent enough to show that $d$ is a metric, you need $d\ge 0$ and $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$. The exercise is senseless.

Comment: @Masacroso That's what I thought, but I couldn't come up with a counterexample.

Comment: A huge load of counterexamples are here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23390/examples-of-non-symmetric-distances

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp try just two points, $M=\{a,b\}$, $d(a,b)=1$, $d(b,a)=-1$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp maybe metric based in a p-norm with $p\in(0,1)$ with a minus multiplying the result. Then the 2 statements hold (subadditivity and 0 if is the same number).

Comment: I updated the question, sorry

Comment: What does "and application" mean? And why wouldn't my previous comment provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have a function $d: M\times M \to \mathbb R$ satisfying -

a) $d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$

b) $d(x,z) \le d(x,y)+d(z,y)$

As you noted, you just have to show that it takes non-negative values and that the symmetry property is satisfied. Also you need to show triangle inequality (which is obvious from (b) once you've shown symmetry)

To show non-negativity (as you have done) -
$$d(x,x)\le d(x,y)+d(x,y) \implies 0 \le 2d(x,y)\implies d(x,y)\ge0$$

To show symmetry we play around with (b)-

Taking $y=x$ in (b) we get, $$d(x,z)\le d(x,x)+d(z,x) \implies d(x,z) \le d(z,x)$$ Similarly interchanging $x$ and $z$ and taking $y=z$ we get,
$$d(z,x)\le d(z,z)+d(x,z) \implies d(z,x) \le d(x,z)$$ So that $$d(x,z)=d(z,x)$$