# Is there a name for the concept of adding "wind" to a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology, line-integrals

Let say we have a metric space $(M,d)$ (in particular, we will require it to be a [length metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric)). If an airplane in that space that moves at speed of 1, then it can get from point $a$ to point $b$ in $d(a,b)$ time.

Now let us suppose we add wind to this space. By wind, I mean we assign to each point $x$ a vector $w(x)$.

When the airplane is at point $a$ moving in direction $v$ (which is a unit vector), it "moves" according to $v + w(a)$. In affect, the wind is blowing against it.

We know define a [quasimetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Quasimetrics) (M, d') as follows. $d'(a,b)$ is defined as the shortest possible amount of time it would take the airplane to get from point $a$ to point $b$ (or $\infty$ if the airplane can't get to $a$ from $b$).

Is there a name for this concept of turning a metric into a quasimetric by adding "wind" to the space?

Examples:

- If we define $w(x)=\vec 0$ for all $x$, then $(M,d) = (M,d')$.
- If we take a circle, and define $w(x)$ as a unit vector going clockwise, we get the quasimetric defined in the first paragraph [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23397/49592) (except the distances are halved).

Comment: Perhaps *geometric group action*, if you think of the wind as describing a transformation of the space sending points on the space to other points on the space. Is the airplane blown only by wind, or can it move under its own power?

Comment: I'm not sure what this means, but perhaps it's a typo: $v+w(a)$ instead of $v+d(a)$?

Comment: @user326210 it can move under it's own power. It has a constant air speed of 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of thing is modelled using Finsler metrics.

If you like wind, then Zermelo navigation metrics is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with a riemannian manifold, let $g_p $ be the inner product in $T_pM$ (a positive definite matrix whose entries vary smoothly) . Given a scalar smooth function $w(p) > 0$, consider the new inner product $h_p= w(p) g_p$ (you multiply the entire matrix by a number).

Recall that the length of a path $\gamma: (-1,1) \to M$ is 
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \gamma'(t) ^T g_{\gamma(t)} \gamma'(t) dt $$
With the modified version of metrics, you have an extra factor $w(\gamma(t)) $. If you started with an airplane having velocity 1 in the old metrics, you have $\gamma'(t) ^T g_{\gamma(t)} \gamma'(t)=1$; so with the extra factor you get that the new distance is $\int w(\gamma(t)) dt $.This means that in points with "high" wind you will have high $w(p) $ (which in some sense measure how much it is difficult to go over a point).

This is not exactly what you wanted because this change is linear, but it can be a good approximation when the wind is little and it can be assumed to be proportional to the velocity.